# Capybara - Selenium - Ruby - testing dynamic id

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have following element (radio-button)which I need to select

```
input class="pull-left" data-class="then-radio-button" id="condition_fields_24934_condition_action_hide" name="condition_fields[24934][condition_action]" type="radio" value="hide"
```

How do I select it considering that part of id name is *dynamic* - particularly in my example it's *24934* which changes every time I run the test?

I use Ruby for writing the tests.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider using cssSelector instead? In such case css is the best option and you can use partial search with that.

```
[id^='condition_fields_'][data-class='then-radio-button']
```

Translation: id->starts with `condition_fields_` and having data-class `then-radio-button`

**Edit**

For additional filtering adding value may be helpful as well.

```
[id^='condition_fields_'][data-class='then-radio-button'][value='hide']
```

Comment: I was trying to use the suggestion and following syntax  find(:css, '[id^='condition_fields_'][data-class='then-radio-button']').click  and this did not work for me. What did i do wrong?

Comment: This almost worked for me! Thank you! Only problem now is that two elements are matching this css, one element has

Comment: input checked="checked" class="pull-left" data-class="then-radio-button" id="condition_fields_24939_condition_action_show" name="condition_fields[24939][condition_action]" type="radio" value="show"

Comment: and second (which I need) has                                                                 input class="pull-left" data-class="then-radio-button" id="condition_fields_24939_condition_action_hide" name="condition_fields[24939][condition_action]" type="radio" value="hide"

Comment: So, there is only difference in the end of id and value. I know how would I select first, but do not know how to select second

Answer (score 0):

Mapping element by suffix:

```
cssSelector = [id*='_condition_action_hide']
```

or by prefix:

```
cssSelector = [id^='condition_fields_']
```